# prevent detection of page range from postnote

Tags: biblatex

I have a book which uses a page number format like `chapter-page`, for instance `1-4` is page 4 in chapter 1. When I use such a page in the postnote for a citation command, `biblatex` thinks this is a page range and adds `pp`. How can I convince `biblatex` that this is just a single page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest is to tell `biblatex` you have a single page manually with `\pno` (you'd use `\ppno` for more than one page)

```
\cite[\pno~1-4]{sigfridsson}
```

or using `\ppspace` instead of `~`

```
\cite[\pno\ppspace1-4]{sigfridsson}
```

You could also go with

```
\DeclareNumChars*{-}
```

but that way `-` will always be seen as a legitimate part of a page number and never as a range separator. So I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks, now that I know the command I can also find the relevant documentation ;-)